# Executing an http.get(all) after a http.post(object) in Angular2 Typescript class

Tags: http, post, get, angular, refresh

I have a method that should execute a http.post(object) and then, after adding a new row (object) to my DB, it should execute a http.get() for a select of the whole table AFTER adding with post. My code is here:

```
getMyObj(): Observable<MyObj[]> {

  return this.http.get(this.myGetUrl)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
}

postMyObj(myObj: MyObj){
  var data= '?param1='+myObj.param1.+'&param2='+myObj.param2';
  let body = JSON.stringify('json');
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  this.http.post(this.myPostUrl+data,body,options)
     .subscribe(()=>this.getMyObj());
}
```

When i add a row in my remote table on my db i can't obtain a complete get AFTER the insert, sometimes it performs the get BEFORE the insert, or it doesn't perform get at all.

How to fix it? I'd like to obtain a refresh of the page in the end of the postMyObj() method, but it seems to execute get or post randomly.

Comment: Are the requests executed in the right order in dev tools? Otherwise you could leverage the `do` operator to see when the requests actually end: `this.http.get(this.myGetUrl).do((data) => console.log(...));`. Otherwise your code seems correct.

Comment: I did it with subscribe() method of OnComplete return using observables.